# Trouble with a "simple" hash merging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, merge

How to 'depp_merge!' this

```
# @user
<User id: nil, name: "Test name", surname: "Test surname", email: nil, password: nil>
```

with this

```
# @hash
{"name"=>"Test name", "surname"=>"Test surname", "email"=>"test_emaild@test.test", "password"=>nil, "test_attribute"=>"Test attribute name"}
```

**?**

---

I tryed this `@user.attributes.deep_merge!(@hash)` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `@user.update_attributes(@hash)` is for. If that doesn't do what you need, please update your question to include what you expect for the output.

[update_attributes docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes)